# How to get pattern rules to match file names with spaces in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, design-patterns, whitespace, filenames, rule

In the GNU make docs, '%' is documented to match "any nonempty substring". However, it seems it actually only matches non-empty substrings that do not contain whitespace. For example, say you do this:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > "test.c"
echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > "test space.c"
```

Now, you should be able to build these using GNU Make's built-in pattern rules:

```
anthony@Zia:/tmp/foo$ make "test"
cc     test.c   -o test
anthony@Zia:/tmp/foo$ make "test space"
make: *** No rule to make target `test space'.  Stop.
```

The same problem happens when you write a makefile.

```
anthony@Zia:/tmp/foo$ rm test
anthony@Zia:/tmp/foo$ echo 'all: test test\ space' > Makefile 
anthony@Zia:/tmp/foo$ make
cc     test.c   -o test
make: *** No rule to make target `test space', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Even if you explicitly add in a `%: %.c` rule, the result is the same. But if you add in an explicit rule to the Makefile, like this, it works:

```
test\ space: test\ space.c
    $(CC) -o "$@" "$<"     # first char is tab, of course.
```

Is there a trick to get spaces to work with implicit rules?

### edit

I've sent a bug report: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2011-06/msg00002.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe so. The notion of a list of whitespace-separated tokens being passed around as a string is pretty deeply ingrained in make. Those lists are parsed and reparsed. There's a reason why spaces in directory and file names is considered bad practice in the UNIX world.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure spaces in filenames are really considered bad practice in the Linux world anymore, except for some limited things like source code files… unfortunately, this stuff came from a vendor. I guess I could file a bug report. Or look for a make alternative.

Comment: I sent a bug report: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2011-06/msg00002.html

Comment: Spaces **are** still considered bad practice in filenames in the Linux world. The only place it is acceptable is user-created filenames. With shell tools, you will (quite simply) suffer if you use spaces.

Comment: It's not a bad practice, but rather a must because of limitations of tools like make, or poorly written shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is a kludge, but as of today, people still get given paths with spaces in sometimes.

Anyway, **making a link** instead of directly accessing the directory in the % rule works OK.

```
# GNU makefile
DIR_WITH_SPACE=/c/Users/me/My\ Code

# *** DOESN'T WORK ***
%.h : $(DIR_WITH_SPACE)/%.h
    cp -v "$<" "$@"

fix:
  ln -s $(DIR_WITH_SPACES) dir_fixed

# Does work :)
%.h : dir_fixed/%.h
    cp -v "$<" "$@"
```