# GCC save temporary output with extra information

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I want to analyze the assembly output of the C program that I am compiling.
To enable GCC save the temporary file I added `-save-temps` option while compiling.

In another [link](https://panthema.net/2013/0124-GCC-Output-Assembler-Code/) I found following GCC options to produce extra output in the assembly code. How to use this option in conjunction with `-save-temps` to produce more readable assembly output? I also want to be sure that assembly file that I am viewing corresponds to the binary produced by the GCC.

> ```
> -a[sub-option...]    turn on listings
>                  Sub-options [default hls]:
>                  c      omit false conditionals
>                  d      omit debugging directives
>                  g      include general info
>                  h      include high-level source
>                  l      include assembly
>                  m      include macro expansions
>                  n      omit forms processing
>                  s      include symbols
>                  =FILE  list to FILE (must be last sub-option)
> ```

Comment: Try `-fverbose-asm`.

Comment: For more tips on **making the asm output human readable**, see also: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38552509/224132)

Comment: okay, I think it helps. thank you !

Comment: The `-a` option only applies to the assembler. It doesn't do anything to change the assembly output of GCC. It affects the assembly listing file that assembler generates, which is formatted version of the assembly input showing the machine code that the assembler generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output): lots of ways to make compiler asm output easier to read.

---

`-Wa,xyz=FILE` makes an *extra* output file alongside the normal output.  It's orthogonal to `-save-temps`.  If you want it to go to a file, you do need an extra output filename on the command line.

e.g. in a [Makefile pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html):

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c  $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Wa,-adhln=$*.lst $< -o $@
```

Put that in a file called Makefile (with the indent being a real TAB, not spaces), then you can:

```
$ CFLAGS='-O3 -g -fverbose-asm' make rnd10.o
cc -c  -O3 -g -fverbose-asm  -Wa,-adhln=rnd10.lst rnd10.c -o rnd10.o

$ ll rnd10.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 912 Mar  3  2016 rnd10.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 25K Sep  6 08:23 rnd10.lst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 12K Sep  6 08:23 rnd10.o
```

So both the .o and the listing were created by the same command.  If you used `-save-temps`, there's also be the preprocessed source, and the actual `.s` that was fed to the assembler, but there's probably not much point in saving those and a listing at the same time.  (I chose `.lst` because it's not in a format that will assemble)

---

**You *may* be able to get away with just adding `-Wa,-adhln=$*.lst` to your `CFLAGS`**, instead of overriding the pattern rule.  This will still only work for build systems that use Make, not alternatives that don't ultimately generate a Makefile (e.g. `scons`), because the `$*` expansion to the stem of the pattern rule is specific to Make.  It also only works for Make pattern rules, not explicit `foo.o : foo.c foo.h` style rules.

e.g.

```
$ rm Makefile
$ CFLAGS='-O3 -g -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln=$*.lst' make rnd10.o
cc -O3 -g -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln=rnd10.lst   -c -o rnd10.o rnd10.c
```

Fun fact: Make [doesn't even work with spaces in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233574/how-to-get-pattern-rules-to-match-file-names-with-spaces-in-makefile), but you can protect from shell expansion of anything else (like `foo$(echo)_weirdname.c`) with single quotes in the build command part of the rule, and in CFLAGS.  e.g. `CFLAGS="-O3 -g "\'-Wa,-adhln=\$\*.lst\' make -B 'foo$(echo)weirdfil\\.o'`